# DirectX 11 input read methods

Tags: c++, directx-11

I'm writing an application now and i need to include inputs to this app. I'm confused now a bit. I heard about four options. 
1. Basic windows messages system,
2. DirectInput8,
3. RawInput,
4. XInput.

I need to distinguish:
1. uppercase letters from lowercase letters, 
2. arrows and special keys from other chars (i mean left arrow key is translated to % when usgin translate message and it's problem coz i need to dostingush them),
3. it would be good if it would be possible proceed data as messages.

Now, my question is: Which one of these four would you use to implement input? Maybe you have another good way to do this?

PS. I need to handle mouse and keyboard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't need joystick gamepad support plain window messages work for everything.

To read character data that will be displayed on screen like text being entered into an input box use [WM_CHAR](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646276%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), WM_CHAR will return different codes for `a` and `A`.

For input keys like left/right arrows etc. you can use [WM_KEYDOWN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646280%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) / [WM_KEYUP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646281%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Windows messages work well for mouse clicks too and for mouse position I prefer to use [GetCursorPos](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648390%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and translate it into the client window coordinates.

For other input devices [XInput](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee417014%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is the prefered choice.

Comment: Ok, seems legit. I wonder if RawInput or DirectInput is faster and if yes then how much faster? Why don't you use lParam from MouseEvent message to get x and y mouse position?

Comment: I guess it is because mouse movement is one area where I want it to be as fast as possible and I don't want to send messages for every mouse move. I just get the cursor position at the beginning of a frame with `GetCursorPos` and it always worked well for me. Doesn't mean WM_MOUSEMOVE won't work. Also input 99.99% of the time won't be your bottleneck so don't worry about it's performance. Windows messages are the suggested way of checking input in windows programming.

Comment: But how do you block sending wm_mousemove message?

Comment: I don't block it windows still sends that message to the window, I just don't do anything for it in my `WndProc` so it falls in to the default handler and DefWindowProc gets called for it.

Comment: But now, let's say i press an left arrow key. System generate a message wm_keydown. Then i peek it from queue and what now? Should i translate it or not? If i do then i recive % and if now then i recive arrow, moreover if i translate it i will recive two messages later wm_keydown and wm_char. I'm a bit confused how i can distinguish % from arrow...

Comment: When I receive a WM_KEYDOWN I call a function and pass the wparam which is virtual key code, so in my application I just check that code against VK_LEFT. Similary if a WM_CHAR is received wparam is the char code of that character.

Comment: Well... Yeah, it sounds quite fair.